# Windows batch file getting data from text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, cmd, find

So I have an output file log file from a video game (mugen in case you're interested):

```
[Match 1]
totalmatches = 1
team1.1 = 
team2.1 = 
stage = stages/stage0-720.def

[Match 1 Round 1]
winningteam = 1
timeleft = 76.70
p1.name = Batman
p1.life = 988
p1.power = 1559
p2.name = Gambit
p2.life = 0
p2.power = 1139

[Match 1 Round 2]
winningteam = 1
timeleft = 78.10
p1.name = Batman
p1.life = 1111
p1.power = 2839
p2.name = Gambit
p2.life = 0
p2.power = 2092

[Match 1 Round 3]
winningteam = 1
timeleft = 74.07
p1.name = Batman
p1.life = 853
p1.power = 3000
p2.name = Gambit
p2.life = 0
p2.power = 3000
```

There's three things I want from this text file:

1. the name of the first fighter which is listed under p1.name = Batman
   (in this case)
2. the name of the second fighter which is listed under p2.name = Gambit (in this case)
3. the winner of the match which you can work out by the winning team in the last round. Winning team is batman in this case because
   the winning team is 1 and he is player 1.

How on earth do I store find this information and put it in variables using a windows .bat script? I'm really struggling by trying to use the find command.

I'm open to using different languages so long as I can get the end result back in the .bat file.

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: @aschipfl I would have done so but it didn't even remotely work, sorry!

Comment: **witch** of the three `p1.name` ?

Comment: @Stephan Any is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in program findstr to do this. Replace logfile.txt with the name of your log.

```
findstr "p1.name p2.name winningteam" logfile.txt
```

if you want to save the output to another file, you can use the '>' (redirect) character.

```
findstr "p1.name p2.name winningteam" logfile.txt > output.txt
```